# GUI app with Web Technology that can take screenshots

Tags: desktop-application

I was given a task to prototype a Desktop Application with the ff. requirements:

1. Must use javascript, nodewebkit, node.js
2. Must be multi platform specially Windows and OSX
3. Can take a screenshot of a certain area where a use can point and drag
4. Must be able to watch multiple directories for changes

Mostly `1,2,4` are possible but I can't get my head around (3) how I will take screen shots on specific areas depending on user point and drag input with only web technologies?

What are ideas on this? I also plan to use angularJS/css for the UI.

Comment: It *may* be possible using the newer media api's (but don't hold me to it).  Or if node-webkit offers you access to the underlying OS (ie, Windows GDI).  But why the insistence on web technologies when something like that is *trivial* for a standard desktop application?

Comment: @GrandmasterB probably to reuse most of the forms from the web app to the desktop app. This is just some kind of clone of the web app to the desktop with the automated filling of forms and screenshots and some file system API stuff. So yeah, but if not web technology (we are a web company) then what could work?

Comment: You can use basically any language that's designed for desktop applications - C++, C#, Delphi, Python, for example.